# What algorithm should I use to optimize a bike sharing redistribution system?

Tags: python, machine-learning, matlab, heuristics

I want to optimize a bike-sharing redistribution system( find the best way for an agent to take bikes from a station that has more bikes than needed and relocate them to a station that needs more bikes) and I don't know what technologies to use.

I have details about the path cost and the demand for each station.

I would like to have multiple solutions and compare them.

Thanks!

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Sounds like a MILP, which you can code up using many technologies like Gurobi, CPLEX, etc. depending on the structure of the costs you may only have one unique optimum — if not then you will get multiple options.